# Access a cell in Excel worksheet with C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to access a cell in Excel worksheet with C#. I tried to use the followed code:

```
if (xlWorksheet.Cells[k + 5, 0] == Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[i, 3].Value))
{ 
     p = k;
}
```

The following message appears in Visual Studio:

`Error  1   One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?`

Comment: explain, what really do you want to do with your code?!!! there is no problem to access cell value. ...

Comment: This code doesn´t work. In this code I just want to compare a Excel worksheet cell with a datatable in AutoCad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (xlWorksheet.Cells[k + 5, 0].Text == Convert.ToString(ent.Cells[i, 3].Value   ))
   { 
     p = k;
   }
```